# How to prove $\nabla F (z_1, ..., z_n) = \mathbf{0}$ implies $F(z_1, ..., z_n) = 0$? (for $F$ homogeneous polynomial)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $F(x_1, ..., x_n)$ be a homogeneous form with integer coefficients and in $n$ variables. Suppose $\mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{C}^n$ satisfies $\nabla F (z_1, ..., z_n) = (\partial F/\partial_{x_1} (z_1, ..., z_n), ..., \partial F/\partial_{x_n} (z_1, ..., z_n) )= \mathbf{0}$. I have learned that this condition alone implies that in fact this point satisfies $F(z_1, ..., z_n) = 0$ (i.e. that it is in fact a singular point of $F=0$)? I was wondering how I can prove this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $F$ is homogeneous then Euler's formula says that $m F(x) = x\cdot \nabla F(x)$ where $m$ is the homogeneous degree of $F$.